# use own Facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've following code:

```
<span><small>
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i><a href="#">56 Likes</a>
</small></span>
```

which gives like button as : 
[image: Custom Facebook Like]

I've included facebook like button as instructed in:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

But I need same functionality. So that when user clicks on the heart icon it get liked and increases count number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to autorize the user and use `og.likes`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes

It is not possible to copy the functionality of the Like Button in any other way afaik. You are not allowed to change the appearance of the Like Button anyway:

> Don’t obscure or cover elements of social plugins

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/